# Flex 3.5 - Panel Title Text Padding

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Is there anyway for me to adjust the padding (left and right) of the text within a Panel Title in Felx 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `textIndent` style, but that will only affect the "padding" to the left. I haven't looked into it, but you may also be able to set the `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` styles as well.

From [Flex Examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/14/indenting-a-flex-panel-controls-title/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/14/indenting-a-flex-panel-controls-title/ -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:Style>
        .myPanelTitle {
            textIndent: 50;
        }
    </mx:Style>

    <mx:Panel title="Lorem ipsum"
            titleStyleName="myPanelTitle"
            titleIcon="@Embed('assets/images/accept.png')"
            width="200">
        <mx:Text text="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
                width="100%" />
    </mx:Panel>

</mx:Application>
```